# Вопрос по Python. list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
numbers = [77, 293, 28, 242, 213, 285, 71, 286, 144, 276, 61, 298, 280, 214, 156, 227, 228, 51, -4, 202, 58, 99, 270,
           219, 94, 253, 53, 235, 9, 158, 49, 183, 166, 205, 183, 266, 180, 6, 279, 200, 208, 231, 178, 201, 260, -35,
           152, 115, 79, 284, 181, 92, 286, 98, 271, 259, 258, 196, -8, 43, 2, 128, 143, 43, 297, 229, 60, 254, -9, 5,
           187, 220, -8, 111, 285, 5, 263, 187, 192, -9, 268, -9, 23, 71, 135, 7, -161, 65, 135, 29, 148, 242, 33, 35,
           211, 5, 161, 46, 159, 23, 169, 23, 172, 184, -7, 228, 129, 274, 73, 197, 272, 54, 278, 26, 280, 13, 171, 2,
           79, -2, 183, 10, 236, 276, 4, 29, -10, 41, 269, 94, 279, 129, 39, 92, -63, 263, 219, 57, 18, 236, 291, 234,
           10, 250, 0, 64, 172, 216, 30, 15, 229, 205, 123, -105]


def f1(x):
    return 9 < abs(x) < 100 and x % 7 == 0


lst = list(map(f1, numbers))
print(lst)
```

Здравствуйте.
В теории, функция должна была заносить в список lst двухзначные числа, которые нацело делятся на 7.

Почему у меня на выходе получается список, наполненный True или False, а не числами?
Спасибо.

Comment: `map` -> `filter`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Потому что вы возвращаете результат условия